# Add line break after 3 commas

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like

```
"tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33"
```

i want to add line break after 3 commas each

```
"tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, </br> cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, </br> mn: 33"
```

Comment: No home work please, let us know what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `for` loop would be the most straightforward and clear solution but it is interesting to do it using LINQ:

```
string input = "tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33";
char delimiter = ',';
var allParts = input.Split(delimiter);
string result = allParts.Select((item, index) => (index != 0 && (index+1) % 3 == 0)
                    ? item + delimiter + " </br>"
                    : index != allParts.Count() - 1 ? item + delimiter : item)
                    .Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);

// result (without a comma after the last item)
// "tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, </br> cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, </br> mn: 33"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code part, it will work fine.

```
string input = "tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33";
            string[] parts = input.Split(','); 
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 1;
            while(i <= parts.Length) 
            {
                result.Append(parts[i-1] + ","); 
                if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    result.Append("<br />");
                }
                i++;
            }
```

EDIT:

```
   result = result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf(','), 1);
   MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: Does the last item `mn: 33` will be followed by a comma `,`?

Answer (score 2):

```
string line ="tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+?:\s+\d+,\s){3}");
string result = regex.Replace(line, "$&<br /> ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do with a LINQ solution:

```
    var count = 0;
    input.Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(),
        (sb, ch) =>
        {
            sb.Append(ch);
            if (ch == ',' && ++count % 3 == 0) sb.Append(" </br>");
            return sb;
        }).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string splitter = ", ";
string newLine = "<br/>";
int splitAfter = 3;
string s = "tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33";
string x = 
   s.Split(new[]{splitter}, StringSplitOptions.None) // Split
    // Make each string entry into a Tuple containing the string itself 
    // and an integer key declaring into which group it falls
    .Select((v, i) => 
       new Tuple<int, string>((int) Math.Floor((double) i/splitAfter), v)) 
    // Group by the key created in the line above
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Item1)
    // Since the key is not needed any more select only the string value
    .Select(g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Item2) 
    // Join the groups 
    // (in your example each group is a collection of 3 elements)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + splitter + b)) 
    // Join all the groups and add a new line in between
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + splitter + newLine + b);
```

That's doing it with "one line" of LINQ. Although I'm not quite sure if that is really desirable considering that it is probably pretty hard for another developer to understand what's happening here at first sight (especially if you don't have much experience with LINQ and especially its GroupBy function).

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in `spliterAfter` variable since it used in LINQ query as `splitAfter`, also I've rrat your query and got `"tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33"` in `x` variable, looks like the same as input string, have you verified the query?

Comment: Ah yes it should be "splitAfter" of course. Thanks for letting me know! And yes the splitter was wrong (splitting by " ," doesn't yield any result because there is no " ," in the string, the splitter should be ", ").

Answer (score 1):

As another option (though the `for` loop approach will be more performant, I like how short this is),

assuming an extension method like this one:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
{
    return source.Where((x,i) => i % chunkSize == 0).Select((x,i) => source.Skip(i * chunkSize).Take(chunkSize));
}
```

Which breaks an `IEnumerable<T>` into an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, you could use the following:

```
var s = "tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33";
var result = string.Join(", </br>", s.Split(',').Split(3).Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

from my very limited programming knowledge, i would use an int to count how many names have been written. (int nameCount = 0). Every time i wrote a name i would increment the counter if it was less than 3 otherwise i would place a line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
string [] parts = yourString.Split(',');
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
  result.Append(parts[i]);
  if(i % 3 == 0)
  {
    result.Append("<br />");
  }
}
```

Comment: your code will not give the output which he wants please check once.

Comment: The final result set should contain comma symbols `,`

Comment: Oops, forgot about commas. @skk's answer is better than mine.

Comment: @Bismark : I would not agree regarding latter, because your answer is more clear. I would preffer to keep such simple `for` loop rather than messy LINQ query for such a simple case

Comment: @sll, skk's answer doesn't get LINQ involved.It basically uses almost the same loop, but also does add commas.

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want, you can use indexof in a foreach and then do something like that:

strTarget.Insert(strTarget.IndexOf(thirdcomma), "");

I think you can create some logic with that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

Ademar

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 string[] split = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
             int count =0;
             for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
             {
                 count+=1;
                 if (i < split.Length - 1)
                 {
                     textBox2.Text += split.GetValue(i) + ",";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     textBox2.Text += split.GetValue(i);
                 }
                 if (count == 3)
                 {
                     count = 0;
                     textBox2.Text += " </br> ";
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your required output:

```
        string combinedValues = "tom: 1, john: 3, timmy: 5, cid: 8, ad: 88, hid: 99, mn: 33";
        string[] separatedValues = combinedValues.Split(',');
        for (int i = 3; i < separatedValues.Count(); i = i + 3)
        {
            separatedValues[i] =  @"<br />" + separatedValues[i];
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string value in separatedValues)
        {
            sb.Append(value);
            sb.Append(@",");
        }
        string combinedValuesWithBreak = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Does the last item `mn: 33` will be followed by the comma `,` symbol?